# iOS App Mapview Line Draw

Tags: swift3, mapkit

Having problem in displaying polyline on the mapview

Following this tutorial
[MapView Tutorial](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/draw-route-mapkit-tutorial)

Attached is my code.
Annotation is appearing on the map but unable to call the renderer method. Though the delegate is there. 
**Main Problem:** Unable to draw line between two coordinates
**Console Output:** 2017-02-06 22:54:56.770584 MapTest[2329:805733] [LogMessageLogging] 6.1 Unable to retrieve CarrierName. CTError: domain-2, code-5, errStr:((os/kern) failure)
Here is the code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1.
        myMap.delegate = self

        // 2.
        let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.759011, longitude: -73.984472)
        let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.748441, longitude: -73.985564)

        // 3.
        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)

        // 4.
        let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

        // 5.
        let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        sourceAnnotation.title = "Times Square"

        if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
            sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }


        let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        destinationAnnotation.title = "Empire State Building"

        if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
            destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }

        // 6.
        self.myMap.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true )

        // 7.
        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
        directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

        // Calculate the direction
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        // 8.
        directions.calculate {
            (response, error) -> Void in

            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }

                return
            }

            let route = response.routes[0]
            self.myMap.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.myMap.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        print("Line 85 is being called......start...")
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0

        print("Line 85 is being called.......end..")
        return renderer
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rendererForOverlay function has the wrong syntax; Xcode told me this when testing your code. Use

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
```

Instead, and a line will be drawn between the two points.